# Getting TypeError in WHEN and OTHERWISE condition statements pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm not able to get past this:

with the below code Im getting

`TypeError: when() missing 1 required positional argument: 'value'`

```
windowval=(Window.partitionBy('Location').orderBy('month_in_timestamp')
               .rangeBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, 0))

df1 = df.withColumn('NEW_COL', F.when(col('col1'). \
                                     isin('data1', \
                                          'data2', \
                                          'data3', \
                                          'data4',F.sum('col2').over(windowval))) \
                                          ,F.when(col('col1'). \
                                     isin('data5', \
                                          'data6', \
                                          'data7', F.avg('col2').over(windowval))))
```

I tried this as well, and Im getting

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: otherwise() can only be applied on a Column previously generated by when()`

```
df_actual_ytd = df_tgt_reach.withColumn('NEW_COL', F.when(col('col1'). \
                                     isin('data1', \
                                          'data2', \
                                          'data3', \
                                          'data4',F.sum('col2').over(windowval))) \
                                          .otherwise(F.avg('col2').over(windowval)))
```

Answer (score 2):

I tried to rework your indentation to understand your `when` clause, add made some correction s that seem necessary.
I cannot test the updated code as I do not have the context:

```py
df1 = df \
    .withColumn('NEW_COL',
                F.when(F.col('col1').isin('data1', 'data2', 'data3', 'data4', F.sum('col2').over(windowval)),
                        F.when(F.col('col1').isin('data5', 'data6', 'data7'), F.avg('col2').over(windowval))
                        )
                )
```

I'm not sure you wanted to have a new `when()` clause if your first condition is matched, but anyway the 2nd `when()` did not have the value if the requirements were met. According to another topic, here is an alternative:

```py
df1 = df \
    .withColumn('NEW_COL',
                F.when(F.col('col1').isin('data1', 'data2', 'data3', 'data4'), F.sum('col2').over(windowval))
                .when(F.col('col1').isin('data5', 'data6', 'data7'), F.avg('col2').over(windowval))
                )
```

If this is what you want, you might also add an `.otherwise()` statement at one point.